# SQL MYSQL Select records excluding rows where any duplicates exist

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, updates

I have the following data

```
 id |   bill_of_lading |  shipping_rate | 
____|__________________|________________|
   1|              8012|              90|
   2|              6045|              90|
   3|              6045|               0|
   4|              2423|               0|
   5|              5342|              90|
   6|              5643|              90|
   7|              5643|               0|
   8|              7545|               0|
   9|              9034|               0|
```

I want to return the rows that have only 1 occurrence of the bill_of_lading number and use the results to update the shipping_rate on records where the shipping rate is zero.

for example,  I would like to set the shipping rate to 220 on ids {4, 8, 9} but not on ids {3, 7}

I'm completely uncertain of the syntax to use for a scenario like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT bill_of_lading, COUNT(*)
FROM t
GROUP BY bill_of_lading
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

See it in action: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/842d0/2

To use the result for updating the corresponding rows, simply join with it:

```
UPDATE t
JOIN (
    SELECT bill_of_lading, COUNT(*)
    FROM t
    GROUP BY bill_of_lading
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) AS selection USING (bill_of_lading)
SET shipping_rate = 220
```

See that one in action: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87b61/1

Comment: That's a great answer.  sqlfiddle.com is cool, I'll have to remember that one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET shipping_rate = 220 
WHERE shipping_rate = 0 AND 
      id IN (SELECT id FROM (SELECT id FROM tablename 
             GROUP BY bill_of_lading HAVING COUNT(id) = 1) as A)
```

Comment: Shouldn't that throw an "You can't specify target table ..." error?

Answer (score 0):

Try this on for size, someone else might have something a little more elegant

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS total FROM table_name GROUP BY bill_of_lading HAVING total = 1
```